# sed delete lines httpd.conf

Tags: sed

I have a `httpd` config file from which I would like to delete the a whole block:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride None

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

from `<Directory "/var/www/html">` to the closing `</Directory>`.

I tried:

```
 sed '/-<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/-<\/Directory>/d' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

but without success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your command does not work because of the dashes before the `<Directory ...>` (and `</Directory>`) statements. This should work:

```
sed '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/<\/Directory>/d' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Also, to make this more readable, you may want to use another character as delimiter than `/`, for example, `#`, like so;

```
sed '\#<Directory "/var/www/html">#,\#</Directory>#d' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

`-` is not needed because your file don't have `-` before `<Directory ...`.

Try this:

```
sed '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/<\/Directory>/d' filename
```